# How to bind color in Avalonia

Tags: c#, xaml, avaloniaui

In WPF it was a bit more confusing how to bind colors, like background color to a viewmodel property.

Are there other ways to bind Colors in Avalonia ?

Or is this example a good way ?

Avalonia View

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Button.Views.MainWindow"
    Title="Button" Width="700">
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Gap="8" Margin="10"> 
      <TextBox Name="Textbox3" Text="{Binding Textbox3Text}" Foreground="{Binding Textbox3Foreground}"/>    
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Avalonia ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private IBrush _textbox3Foreground;

    public IBrush Textbox3Foreground
    {
        get { return _textbox3Foreground; }
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _textbox3Foreground, value);
        }
    }    

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
         Textbox3Foreground = Brushes.DarkOliveGreen;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that you have set the `DataContext` of the window to an instance of your view model class:

```
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Button.Views.MainWindow"
    Title="Button" Width="700">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Gap="8" Margin="10">
        <TextBox Name="Textbox3" Text="{Binding Textbox3Text}" Foreground="{Binding Textbox3Foreground}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In general you don't usually define UI related things such as colours in the view model though. These kind of things are usually defined directly in the view without any bindings. But you can certainly bind to a `Brush` property like this.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I am just playing around with avalonia, its great !